# How to use VLOOKUP to split multiple-valued cell into separate rows?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, powerquery

As the title says, how do you split this
[image]

into

[image]

Comment: What makes that you specifically ask for `VLOOKUP`. Have you attempted something? If so, please include in your question to make this a question with a [mcve]. To me, this looks like something done quickly through `PowerQuery`

Comment: Where does the ***_NEW*** come from?

Comment: I am afraid that you should use VBA... Anyhow, check @JvdV comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure where the `VLOOKUP` comes from in your question, but if you have Excel 2010 or later you can do this through `PowerQuery`

[image]

- Select your data
- `Data` tab > `From Table/Range`
- You have headers, so choose accordingly

PowerQuery should now start, and within the opened tab:

- `Start` tab > `Split column` > `by delimiter`
- Obviously choose a comma as delimiter > Choose `Advanced` and tick by `Row` instead of `Column`.
- Choose no quotes and confirm.
- Right click the data in PQ > `Transform` > `Trim`

That's it. You can close PowerQuery now and save your changes

[image]

I would post the `M` code, but my Excel is in Dutch so no use.

Comment: @SolarMike, what do you mean? Is there a more straightforward text to column (read: rows) option?

Comment: I didn't even know PowerQuery exist! That helped me a lot, thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you are not dealing with a massive amount of data, and using Excel 365 or later versions, you can try the following solution.

Suppose your original data is in range `A1:A4` including header,

Highlight range `B1:B10`, go to your formula bar and enter the following formula and confirm it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on your keyboard:

```
=FILTERXML("<a><b>"&TEXTJOIN("</b><b>",,SUBSTITUTE(A1:A4,", ","</b><b>"))&"</b></a>","//b")
```

[image: Demo]

If you do not want to show the `#N/A` error, you can use the **IFERROR** formula in the following way:

```
=IFERROR(formula,"")
```

> For the logic behind the use of **FILTERXML** function, you can give a read to this article: [Extract word by position using FILTERXML()](https://chandoo.org/wp/extract-words-with-filterxml/)

The problem with the above solution is that you need to find out what is a reasonable output range for you to enter the **array formula** so all output can be displayed.

---

If you have joined the "mysterious" *insider program* of Excel, you may be able to simply use the **UNIQUE** function in the following way to get the list (please note the following is only a **guess** as I am not in the program so cannot test it out).

Highlight cell `B1`, enter the following formula, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> key as normal.

```
=UNIQUE(formula)
```

And the list will be *spilled* automatically in range `B1:B6`.

A problem with this formula is that it will only display duplicated values once. Use it with caution.

An alternative is to use **SORT** function which will also generate a list automatically including duplicated values but they will not be in the same order as the original list if the original list is in random order.